# jquery localstorage sorting output

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I am struggling for a long time how to sort the output of the localstorage data.
I want to sort the output (asc) on the stored id of the products. Anyone got a solution how to fix this?

Thx!

```
function showCheckout() {
Cart        = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartStorage'));
cartTbody   = '';

if (Cart) {
    $.each(Cart, function(index, value) {
        if (value !== null) {    
              cartTbody   += '<tr id="row' + value['id'] + '">' +
                '<td> + value['product_name'] + '</td>' + 
            '</tr>';
        } 
    });
}
$( "#cartContainer tbody" ).html(cartTbody);
}
```

Comment: Did you try just a regular sort? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you want to sort Cart before appending each of its elements' informations to a table's row.

I'd sugest inserting rows in your container as you go,  thus placing them to the correct index

```
var $container = $( "#cartContainer tbody" );
$container.empty();
Cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartStorage'));
$.each(Cart, function(index, value) {
    var $row = $("<row/>").attr("id",row + value['id'])
    $("<td/>").text(value['product_name']).appendTo($row);
    //Here you determine where row should be inserted.
    var inserted = false;
    $container.find("row").each(function(){
        if(!inserted && $(this).attr("id").localeCompare(value['id'])>0){
            $(this).before($row);
            inserted = true;
        }
    });
    if(!inserted){
        $container.append($row);
    }
}
```

there is quite a lot of jquery calls in this method so if your array is huge, you'd better just sort it then insert it sequentially for performance sake.